# Get Instagram permission for public_content

Tags: api, permissions, instagram, instagram-api

wish all of the best for you
do me a favor please?
i wanna analyze the media with specific hashtag on instagram, there are many website do that like Keyhole or iconosquare

as i know with 2 type of API, instagram analytics site do that (instagram graph api facebook and instagram platform api)
but as i search in instagram graph api facebook graph there is no option to analyze hashtag and as i search in instagram platform api i read detail about permission as below :
basic - to read a user’s profile info and media
public_content - to read any public profile info and media on a user’s behalf (applications no longer accepted)
follower_list - to read the list of followers and followed-by users (applications no longer accepted)
comments - to post and delete comments on a user’s behalf (applications no longer accepted)
relationships - to follow and unfollow accounts on a user’s behalf (applications no longer accepted)
likes - to like and unlike media on a user’s behalf (applications no longer accepted)
if we wanna analyze via instagram api, we have to gain public_content permission but instagram write (application no longer accepted)
what shall i do know for that?

Answer (score 4):

Instagram stopped giving permission other than basic_profile , so you won't get permission for release and can use only in sandbox mode.

it's waste of time now to use Instagram api.